# Automator Tasks - Safari Not Responding

Tags: safari, macos, automator

I have some daily Automator tasks on my calendar which open URLs in Safari.  (A "Get Specified URLs" task followed by a "Display Webpages" task.)  Ever since upgrading to Yosemite, however, there's been a bit of an issue.  Sometimes several tabs are opened, and it's no longer handling that very well.

Previously, even if Safari was slow, all of the tabs would open when it's available.  Since the Yosemite upgrade, however, only some of the tabs open and the rest pop up a message:

> You can't open the application "Safari" because it is not responding.

Is there a way to tell Automator to wait until Safari responds rather than just fail on some of the URLs?

Answer (score -1):

If you replace the "Display Webpages" task with a "Run AppleScript" task you can control what it does (i.e. add a delay)... I've posted sample code here:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/27244343?ac_cid=op123456

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.